# Integrate facebook connect with Cordova 3.4 on Android

Tags: android, facebook, cordova, cordova-plugins

Has anyone been able to get the facebook connect plugin to work with phonegap 3.4? I'm really struggling to just get to a sanity state with this. I am just trying to do the automatic install. So I have been following the instructions exactly in [the docs](https://github.com/phonegap/phonegap-facebook-plugin).

```
cordova create myApp

cd myApp/

cordova platform add android

cordova -d plugin add https://github.com/phonegap/phonegap-facebook-plugin --variable APP_ID="364700000000802" --variable APP_NAME="My Facebook App"
```

At this point if I try to run `cordova build android` I get this error:

```
BUILD FAILED
/Users/croberts/adt-bundle/sdk/tools/ant/build.xml:720: The following error occurred while executing this line:
/Users/croberts/adt-bundle/sdk/tools/ant/build.xml:734: Compile failed; see the compiler error output for details.

Total time: 10 seconds
Error code 1 for command: ant with args: debug,-f,/Users/croberts/Dropbox/myApp/platforms/android/build.xml,-Dout.dir=ant-build,-Dgen.absolute.dir=ant-gen
Error: /Users/croberts/Dropbox/myApp/platforms/android/cordova/build: Command failed with exit code 2
    at ChildProcess.whenDone (/usr/local/lib/node_modules/cordova/src/superspawn.js:126:23)
    at ChildProcess.EventEmitter.emit (events.js:98:17)
    at maybeClose (child_process.js:735:16)
    at Process.ChildProcess._handle.onexit (child_process.js:802:5)
```

If I don't add the plugin then it builds normally. Maybe after you install facebook-connect you aren't allowed to try to build the project again?

If I add the plugin, and then instead of trying to build for android I just try to open it in eclipse (what the documentation suggests), then the FacebookLib isn't able to find the android.R class.

```
The import com.facebook.android.R cannot be resolved
```

along with an error in the console `Unable to resolve target 'android-8'`

Has anyone done a great tutorial for how to get this thing to work on android? I feel like I have read everything online but haven't found anything that gets the job all the way done.

Answer (score 0):

i also still have hard time to integrate facebook with phonegap....i think this might help u a bit :

http://www.systenics.com/blog/setup-facebook-login-and-camera-for-android-app-using-phonegap-34/

http://www.excellentwebworld.com/integrate-facebook-in-phonegap/

cordova build android error : i also have this when i create package/folder under src org/apache/cordova/facebook/......so i use eclipse add facebook sdk and build...no error....

The only problem i have now is from emulator....it does not work...init login failed....and still trying to figure out what did i missed....peace